# Programatically access an imageview / textview that is part of a layout for a listview

Tags: android, listview, textview, imageview, expandablelistview

I want to change the visibility of an imageview to visible after a button is pressed. I am using an expandable listview and I am getting null pointer exceptions each time I try to change the visibility of the imageview. I'm finding the imageview with findViewById and everything is compiling, but I crash when I try to actually change the imageview's visibility. Is programatically changing textviews / imageviews that are part of a layout for a listview possible? And if so, could you explain how? Also I am getting data from an SQL database and using a SimpleCursorTreeAdapter.

Thank you Nickolai Astashonok!
I was able to use the following code to change the visibility of the imageview that was part of my list layout

```
 SimpleCursorTreeAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorTreeAdapter(this,
                            cursor, R.layout.list_parent, fromParent, toParent,
                            R.layout.list_child, fromChild, toChild) {

        //method overridden to access the imageview
                        @Override
                        protected void bindGroupView (View view, Context context, Cursor cursor, boolean isExpanded) {
                            super.bindGroupView(view, context, cursor, isExpanded);

                       //don't forget to access via the view that was passed in
                            ImageView editIcon= (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ivEdit);
                            editIcon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }

                        @Override
                        protected Cursor getChildrenCursor(Cursor groupCursor) {
                            Long rowId = Long.parseLong(groupCursor.getString(0));

                            startManagingCursor(groupCursor);
                            groupCursor = dbAdapter.getRow(rowId);
                            // grabs the row of data for the appropriate child
                            return groupCursor;
                        }
                    };
```

Comment: post your code,logcat and snapshot of view so we can help you..

Comment: you should trigger visibility in getView method of your adapter. Do you follow this strategy? And of course, examples of your code would help

Answer (score 0):

if the ImageView is part of your `ListView`, declare the ListView first:

```
ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.your_listview);
```

then declare the `ImageView` according to it:

```
ImageView image = (ImageView) list.findViewById(R.id.your_imageview);
```

or if it contained in a Layout in the ListView, declare that layout and declare the ImageView according to it.

Answer (score 0):

```
you can do this in adapter
On getview() method do the changes  :  


  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, parent, false);
    Button btn = (Button) rowView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    textView.setText(values[position]);
      imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.no);
     btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                imageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        });
    }
```